# EXC_RETURN does not work in PendSV on ARM Cortex-M3

Tags: cortex-m, lpc

I want to use EXC_RETURN in PendSV but I always get HardFault with INVPC (Invalid PC load UsageFault, caused by an invalid PC load by EXC_RETURN). This works, if I move the assembly code to Systick_Handler().

What do I miss?

I use [NXP LPC1769](https://www.embeddedartists.com/products/lpc1769-lpcxpresso/) with the latest MCUXpressoIDE.

```
void Systick_Handler(void){
    SCB->ICSR |= SCB_ICSR_PENDSVSET_Msk;
}

__attribute__ ((naked)) void Pendsv_Handler(void) {
    __ASM volatile (
    "NOP    \n"
    "ldr r0, =0xFFFFFFFD \n"
    "bx r0"
    );
}

int main(void) {

    SysTick_Config(100);

    __enable_irq();

    __set_PSP(0x10007800);

    __set_CONTROL(0x3); // Thread mode with PSP

    while(1) {
        __NOP();
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

The Pendsv_Handler() compiled to:

```
          Pendsv_Handler:
000003b4:   nop     
000003b6:   mvn.w   r0, #2
000003ba:   bx      r0
27        }
000003bc:   nop
```

**Update:** Based on Tom V comments. But still not working.

***Solution***

I missed to set the priority of SysTick and PendSV, like:

```
NVIC_SetPriority(PendSV_IRQn, 0xFF);
NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0x00);
```

Comment: Your stack pointer value is not aligned.  ARM uses a full descending stack, so the initial value of the stack pointer should be the address of the first byte after the stack space (I guess 0x10007800 in this case).  Note that this probably is unrelated to the cause of your problem.

Comment: You should check if the compiler has mangled your code by disassembling the build output.  FWIW I suggest writing assembly language functions in an assembly file.

Comment: @TomV: thanks for your comments but it still fails with the same issue :(. The \_\_attribute\_\_ ((naked)) allows me to write assembly code in C without having compiler added code.